# Should I delete my old question with no answers?

Tags: discussion, deletion

My question [How to configure pybuilder's and pytest's paths right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455646/how-to-configure-pybuilders-and-pytests-paths-right) has no answers, no worthwhile comment, it is more than 3 years old, and software specific (about pybuilder and pytest). I guess that pybuilder and pytest have new versions, making the question most likely obsolete. I am also not interested in the question anymore, since it is about an error.

My question [Bugs in lubridate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36717960/bugs-in-lubridate) has no answers, is even more than 4 years old and is closed.

I consider deleting these questions. Is there any reason to not delete them / one of them?

Comment: Can you self answer them after so many years?

Comment: Perhaps use more specific question title?

Comment: @Icepickle: No, I abandoned the respective technology back then, since I was not able to resolve the issues fast enough. I never tried using them again.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: You mean for the questions? Any suggestions? (I don't quite understand how this would help in this case - maybe you can elaborate what you have in mind.)

Comment: If you don't feel the questions are valuable, and you can't answer them, I see no reason not to delete them, but also don't think you have an *obligation* to delete them either. On some level, old, unuseful questions just add clutter to the site, but the algorithms do a fine job of raising fresh, relevant content over the old, so I don't think the questions are doing much harm either. So, a long winded way to say, up to you!